# Ruby on Rails - Need help associating models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, rails-models

Ok, am still a newbie in ruby on rails trying to learn my way around. I have two models (User model and Comment model). Basically a user has a simple profile with an 'about me' section and  a photo's section on the same page. Users must be signed in to comment on other users profiles.

My User Model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :email, :name, :username, :gender, :password, :password_confirmation
        has_secure_password
        has_many :comments
        .
        .
    end
```

My Comment Model

```
    class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :user
       attr_accessible :content
       .
       .
     end
```

In my comments table, I have a `user_id` column that stores the id of the user whose profile has been commented on and a `commenter_id` column that stores the id of the user commenting on the profile.

Comment Form

```
    <%= form_for([@user, @user.comments.build]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, cols: "45", rows: "3", class: "btn-block comment-box" %>
      <%= f.submit "Comment", class: "btn" %>
    <% end %>
```

My comments Controller

```
    class CommentsController < ApplicationController
        def create
           @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
           @comment = @user.comments.build(params[:comment])
           @comment.commenter_id = current_user.id
           if @comment.save
             ......... 
           else
             .........
           end      
        end  
    end
```

This works fine storing both `user_id` and `commenter_id` in the database. My problem comes when displaying the user comments on the show page. I want to get the name of the user who commented on a specific profile.

In my user controller

```
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @comments = @user.comments
      end
```

I want to get the name of the user from the `commenter_id` but it keeps throwing errors `undefined method 'commenter' for #<Comment:0x007f32b8c37430>` when I try something like `comment.commenter.name`. However, `comment.user.name` works fine but it doesn't return what I want. Am guessing am not getting the associations right.

I need help getting the correct associations in the models so as to get the name from the commenter_id.

My last question, how do I catch errors in the comments form? Its not the usual `form_for(@user)` where you do like `@user.errors.any?`.

routes.rb

```
      resources :users do
         resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
      end
```

Comment: In you comment class, you can add a "custom" relation with custom name and foreign key: `belongs_to :commenter, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'`

Comment: See here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to (their example with Person Author and Post) With what I gave you you should be able to do `comment.commenter` and this should return a User object if exists

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :received_comments, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :given_comments, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "commenter_id"
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # comment about profile
  belongs_to :commenter, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "commenter_id"
end
```

check out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

you can probably come up with better naming on the has_many collections, received and given were the best I could do on short notice :)

Note: foreign_key is option in many cases, left it in above - i think it helps with clarity

- has_many fk refers to the the column in the many table (other table)
- belongs_to fk refers to the column in the many table (this table)